# Is there a list/graph of all symbols for a Swedish/Finnish keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I switched to a physical Swedish/Finnish keyboard to save my sanity (too many ä and ö I need to type), but I noticed many symbols are poorly documented, and do not match the equivalent Windows keyboard.  For instance, the symbols | and \ are not where a Windows keyboard puts them (and also, the Windows keyboard does show where these symbols are).  Same is for [] and {}.  I looked online for a quick guide of where the symbols are in an Apple Swedish/Finnish keyboard, but I am still to find one.  I thought Apple would provide it, but I failed to find it.

Does anybody has a list or a picture showing all the symbols one can produce with <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's built-into the OS. Keyboard Viewer

To be able to get to it rapidly… System Prefs > Keyboard > Input Sources > Show input menu in menu bar.
Then you can get to it from the menu

[image]

[image]

Holding various combinations of Shift / Opt will let you see all the glyphs available directly from keyboard combos. Orange keys are dead-keys, which will add an accent to the next-pressed key. Swedish is amongst the few which has permanent dead+keys without needing Opt.
The glyphs you're looking for in Swedish all appear to be on the number keys 7, 8, 9.

The appearance of this panel has changed in recent macOS, but the functionality is very similar.
Above is Mojave, below is Big Sur. The actual layout you will see depends on your physical keyboard too.

[image]

Comment: Well I just need the Finnish keyboard. But thanks to @Tetsujin, that totally solved my question.

Comment: Finnish and Swedish (formerly called Swedish PRO) have the same layout.